# Modify Jackson response

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have two classes:

```
class A {
  int id;
  String name;
}

class B {
  String property1;
  String property2;
  String property3;
}
```

when A extends B

Response:

```
{
  "property1": "value1",
  "property2": "value2",
  "property3": "value3"
  "id":1,
  "name": 'my name"
}
```

Instead, I want to display them as below:

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name": 'my name',
  "property1": "value1",
  "property2": "value2",
  "property3": "value3"
}
```

Comment: Why does the ordering of the keys matter?

Comment: did you try @JsonPropertyOrder?

Answer (score 0):

The order of the fields within JSON object shouldn't matter. As per [the spec](http://www.json.org/):

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

So what you're asking doesn't really make sense.

Comment: jackson has annotation @ JsonPropertyOrder. if above case is true, it brings me confusion

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [JsonPropertyOrder](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html) annotation for this.

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id", "name", "property1", "property2", "property3"})
class B {
    ...
```

Comment: you have another solution?

Comment: @vxba I don't get what are you asking about now

Comment: I'm sorry.
I tried with @JsonPropertyOrde but I see it very inconvenient when having  properties too much